# Не получается навешать хук на CreateFile()

Tags: c++, winapi, файлы, dll, hook

Здравствуйте, вообщем решил начать изучение хуков на WinApi. Прочитал статью https://habrahabr.ru/company/infopulse/blog/140456/. Попытался сделать по аналогии для CreateFileW. Вот код, но при добавлении к процессу(пробовал и к explorer.exe и всяким редакторам), ничего не происходит. API Monitor-ом проверял - функция CreateFileW вызывается. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста, кто уже пробовал работать с Microsoft Detours.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\Detours Express 3.0\src\detours.h"

// Сохраняем реальный указатель на функцию:
HANDLE(WINAPI * TrueCreateFileW)(LPCTSTR lpFileName, DWORD dwDesiredAccess, DWORD dwShareMode, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes, DWORD dwCreationDisposition, DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes, HANDLE hTemplateFile) = CreateFileW;

// Моя, новая функция:
__declspec(dllexport) HANDLE WINAPI MyCreateFileW(LPCTSTR lpFileName, DWORD dwDesiredAccess, DWORD dwShareMode, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes, DWORD dwCreationDisposition, DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes, HANDLE hTemplateFile)
{
    if ((LPCTSTR)lpFileName == (LPCTSTR)"D:\text.txt")
    {
        return TrueCreateFileW((LPCTSTR)"D:\test1.txt", dwDesiredAccess, dwShareMode, lpSecurityAttributes, dwCreationDisposition, dwFlagsAndAttributes, hTemplateFile);
    }
    return TrueCreateFileW(lpFileName, dwDesiredAccess, dwShareMode, lpSecurityAttributes, dwCreationDisposition, dwFlagsAndAttributes, hTemplateFile);
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinst, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID reserved)
{
    if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        DetourRestoreAfterWith();
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)TrueCreateFileW, MyCreateFileW);
        DetourTransactionCommit();
    }
    else if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)
    {
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourDetach(&(PVOID&)TrueCreateFileW, MyCreateFileW);
        DetourTransactionCommit();
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Для изучения есть книга "Windows via C/C++" by Jeffrey Richter and Christophe Nasarre. См. Chapter 22 - DLL Injection and API Hooking.